Angular canActivate guard block the updating meta tags
I have used routes with canActivate guard
{
    path: "profile",
    loadComponent: () => import("./user/profile/profile.component").then(m => m.ProfileComponent),
    canActivate: [LoginAuthGuard]
  }

and try to update or add a meta tag
this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'title', content: 'My Title Here' });
this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: 'My Description Here' });

It doesn't work. But if I remove the canActivate guard from the route configuration then it will work.
Even I tried using resolver but the meta tag did not update.
I'm trying to add or meta tag dynamically with the routes has canActivate Guard.

I guess LoginAuthGuard does not return true.

on the server side, LoginAuthGuard gets false, but on the client side, we are getting true. Then what will be the process for getting true on LoginAuthGuard on the server side also?
